# Why can't I call an inherited version of QWidget::isVisible()?

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading

I have a class `MyDialog` that subclasses `QDialog`, which itself subclasses `QWidget`.  So it looks like this:

```
QObject
   |
   V
QWidget
   |
   V
QDialog
   |
   V
MyDialog
```

The class `MyDialog` has a static method `static bool isVisible( MyObject *myObject )`.  It also inherits an instance method from it's parent: `QWidget::isVisible()`

In MyDialog.h:

```
class MyDialog : public QDialog
{
    static bool isVisible( MyObject *myObject );

    MyDialog *getInstance( MyObject *myObject );

    // other methods
};
```

In MyDialog.cpp:

```
bool MyDialog::isVisible( MyObject *myObject )
{
    // This intended call to QWidget::isVisible() won't compile
    return MyDialog::getInstance( myObject )->isVisible() 
}
```

This fails to compile with the following error:

```
src/MyDialog.cxx: In static member function ‘static bool MyDialog::isVisible(MyObject*)’:
src/MyDialog.cxx:67:57: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyDialog::isVisible()’
src/MyDialog.cxx:67:57: note: candidate is:
src/MyDialog.cxx:62:6: note: static bool MyDialog::isVisible(Equipment*)
src/MyDialog.cxx:62:6: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

It seems to be trying to call my static method `MyDialog::isVisible( MyObject * )` instead of the inherited `QWidget::isVisible()` which matches the signature.  Why?

Comment: You should rename your static method regardless of the cause of the trouble. Such a name conflict is bad practice.

Comment: @Riateche good to know, thanks!  I'll rename it either way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare your static function `isVisible` that has the same name than a function of the base class but a different signature, you're not overloading it but you're actually hiding the inherited function. The compiler sees the function that is implemented in your class but not the inherited `isVisible` function from QWidget.

If you want to call specifically the QWidget version, either change the name of your function (so it doesn't hide it anymore) or qualify the call like this :

```
MyDialog::getInstance( myObject )->QWidget::isVisible();
```